# Assigning values from one array to another in Powershell without encountering null index when de-referencing elements

Tags: powershell

I have an array with fields (a multi dimensional array, if I am correct), my aim is to create another array based on elements filtered from the first.

However when I come to deference `$arr2` by looking at its first element `$arr[0]`, I get the error message:

> Cannot index into a null array

Can someone please provide me with some advise as to the most elegant way of resolving this.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr1.length; $i++) {
    if ($arr1[$i].source -eq $SomeValue) {
        $arr2 += @( $arr1[$i] )
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that's because you haven't initialized `$arr2` anywhere. Trying putting `$arr2 = @()` at the top of your code.

Comment: Personally I may need a little more information to completely understand your situation. First, based on your code, $arr1 is an array of objects. Not a multi-dimensional array. Second, what is the goal of forcing elements to be added to $arr2 as arrays instead of simply adding the element as it is `$arr2 += $arr1[$i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$arr2 = @( $arr1 | Where { $_.source -eq $someValue } )

Comment: This is what I went with in the end   $arr1 = < call function to generate array of objects >
  $arr2 =  $arr1.where({ ([string]$_.Source) -eq $FilterString })